# Why counter is not being displayed in vue js by using getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

As you can see in code below i have store.js where I am doubling my value by 2 using getters but while accessing it in result this.$store.state.doubelCounter; is showing as undefined.

I have this `store.js` for vuex

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        counter: 0
    },
    getters: {
        doubleCounter: state => {
            return state.counter * 2;
        } 
    }
})
```

This one is `counter.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="increment">Increment</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="decrement">Decrement</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            increment() {
                this.$store.state.counter++;
            },
            decrement() {
                this.$store.state.counter--;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is `result.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <p>Counter is: {{ counter }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    counter() {
      return this.$store.state.doubelCounter;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Its a getter not a state. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: For your kind information, i did check the docs. and I am a beginner so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't mutate store's state directly. The only way to do that is to commit a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html):

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  },
  getters: {
    doubleCounter: state => state.counter * 2
  },
  mutations: {
    incrementCounter(state) {
      state.counter++;
    },
    decrementCounter(state) {
      state.counter--;
    }
  },
})
```

Then, in `counter.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="incrementCounter">Increment</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="decrementCounter">Decrement</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    methods: {
      ...mapMutations(['incrementCounter', 'decrementCounter'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

Second, to access store's getter, you should use `$store.getters` instead of `$store.state` in `result.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <p>Counter is: {{ counter }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    counter() {
      return this.$store.getters.doubleCounter; // "doubel" typo fixed
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You btw, I was following the tutorial so, work in tutorial but not in mine , it might be due to the version of Vue

Comment: @SarwanNizamani I think you're just making mistakes here and there. Code from tutorials should work.

Comment: @SarwanNizamani You're welcome. Don't forget to mark my answer as a solution :)